# How to run a libtool executable in Instruments.app

Tags: macos, memory-leaks, libtool

I want to check my os x executable for memory leaks. And I wish to use Instruments.app for that. But I don't know how to execute it in wrapper which libtool creates (adding library paths etc). Can I use something like glibtool --mode=execute myapp for Instruments target. Something like launching gdb on libtool script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should just install the program and then debug it there.  Then there is no libtool in play.  Use an alternative prefix from your real installation, perhaps.